# Java make a for loop while creating variables named by the given loop

Tags: java

I'm wondering how I do the following. Make 10 int variables called, `var_0`, `var_1`, `var_2`, etc.
All holding 0. I'm picturing something like this...

```
for(int i=0;i>10;i++){
   int var_i = 0;
}
```

But of course it doesn't work. How do I make this work without doing every single variable manually?

It's intended for an arbitrary amount of variables.

Comment: If they're all holding 0, why do you need 10 of them??

Comment: I dont know the amount, I see know that int was a bad example. I'll do an array with Objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's impossible in Java, there are no macros that would let you do it. Usually if you need 10 variables with same name you just use array.

```
int vars[] = new vars[10];
```

It will be initialized to zeroes by default.

---

If you don't know number of elements in advance you can declare array and construct it later:

```
int vars[];
...
int numVars = 10;
vars = new int[numVars];
```

Answer (score 1):

> It's intended for an arbitrary amount of variables.

It sounds like you really want an *array* of 10 `int`:

```
int vars[] = new int[10];
```

The elements will be initialized to 0. If you need to initialize to something specific, besides zero:

```
for (int i = 0; i < vars.length; i++)
{
    int vars[i] = 7;
}
```

You could also declare 10 `int`, and initialize them in a single statement:

```
int var1, var2, var3, ...;
var1 = var2 = var3 = ... = 0;
```

Comment: Re: "Note that an `int` in java is initialized to *0* by default": That's not exactly true. *When* an `int` in Java is initialized by default (because it's an element of an array, or it's a non-`final` field, or a `final` field that you've hacked around the initialization requirements for), it's initialized to `0`, but it's not always true that any default initialization takes place: with local variables, the language requires you to perform the initialization, and issues a compile-error if it can't prove that you've done so.

Comment: instance variable `int` will initialize by 0, but not local.

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible, even if it creates it would be local to loop, so why not populate a `List` there

```
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int i=0;i>10;i++){
   numbers.add(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thats not possible, so better go with `arrays`.....

```
int[] arr = new int[10];

for(int i=0 ; i<10 ; i++){


      int[0] = 0;

 }
```